# Some individual dependency properties say that the source of theirs values is a Style, but Style is set to null (not set)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

The answer to this question should be (I hope) the part of the debugging the more complicated case.

Well, now I see that some DPs are set to proper values from a style, but the Style property is set to null (not set. I see it from WPF Visualizer).

Why this happens? What could be the cause?

Comment: Can you post simple XAML code for the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811849/elements-dont-take-fallbackvalues-for-the-style-properties You can see xaml here. These questions are connected)

Comment: I have added a possible answer to 20811849.